# Integrating Bootswatch Theme with Twitter-Bootstrap-Rails Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, twitter-bootstrap-rails, bootswatch

I've got a Ruby on Rails app running with Bootstrap, which I installed using the gem twitter-bootstrap-rails.

I'd now like to integrate a new Bootswatch theme, but I'm having trouble figuring out what to do.

There are four possible downloads for each theme - a `bootstrap.css` file, a `bootstrap.min.css` file, a variables.less file, and a bootswatch.less. My question is: do I need to download and add them ALL to my `~/app/assets/stylesheets` folder? or do I just need a subset of those? Currently inside `~/app/assets/stylesheets` are just two files: `application.css` and `boostrap_and_overrides.css.less`. **LESS** really throws me off here so I'm totally confused with how it works and what I need to do to add new css files with this setup. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to download the bootstrap.css file, and rename it. The bootstrap.min.css is the same as the css file just a minified version of it. Less is just another way of writing css and accessing each property differently. Check out [less](http://lesscss.org/). Add css file and begin integrating into html, also point html to new stylesheet.

Comment: So I'm assuming that if I throw in the bootstrap.css file, rename it to new_theme.css, and add a stylesheet_link_tag (in application.html.haml view) or require (in application.css), the new theme override the default Bootstrap theme where appropriate?

Comment: Yes and also check out their [github](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/blob/master/README.md) page, very valuable information on how to use their bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a twitter bootstrap gem for easy Bootswatch theme integration/customization for rails:

https://github.com/scottvrosenthal/twitter-bootswatch-rails